# Is there a way to automatically update a list of contents of the documents in the nested folders?

Tags: folder, subfolders

So I have a master folder with many subfolders within. I want to maintain a list of under which folder a particular document can be found. I want to maintain separate folders for different topics, but at the same time display which folders contain what documents in the main folder.

I'm clueless as to how to do it. If somebody could give me a general guideline as to how to go about this, I could dig further.

I'm very new to SharePoint and still trying to get a hang of it. So my apologies if this question is already asked. I have looked through the other questions and haven't really gotten the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better served to not use folders.  Utilize columns of metadata to categorize your items.  Then create views of sub-sets of the content using filtering.

https://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/sharepoint-document-libraries-and-horrors-oh-my

Comment: I agree with this because each folder you create can only be manually maintained at each level. Using Columns and creating metadata might be a better way to "filter" all your files by specified choices.